# Change application property value in unit test method

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot

My REST API generates a password on a POST request and stores it in a DB. For development purpose, I'd like to put it in the response, when a development.mode flag is set to true in the application.properties file.

I would like to test this controller and check that if the flag is true, the password is in the response, if false the password is not.

I would like to know if and how I can dynamically set this property value from each test method.

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class PasswordController {

  @Value("${development.mode}")
  private boolean isDevelopmentMode;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<String> generatePassword(@RequestParam(USERNAME_PARAM) String username) {
    String password = manager.generatePassword();

    String body = "";
    if (isDevelopmentMode) {
      body = "New password: " + password;
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.OK);
  }    
}
```

I have seen documentation to define different property files  for testing, using @PropertySource, but it's at the class level and I would like to avoid creating a different file just to change a flag.

I've also seen posts saying you can use ReflectionUtils.setField to change the value of a private field, but for this I have to explicity instantiate my controller and consequently have some issues with Autowired fields. I've tried this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(PasswordControllerTest.class)
public class PasswordControllerTest extends OtpTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void newRoute_developmentModeIsFalse_responseBodyIsEmpty() throws Exception {
    PasswordController controller = new PasswordController();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(controller, "isDevelopmentMode", false);
    MockMvc mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new PasswordController()).build();
    given(manager.generatePassword(any(String.class))).willReturn("123456");
    mvc.perform(post("/new").param(PasswordController.USERNAME_PARAM, "test_user")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().string(""));
  }
}
```

Is there a possibility to set the value of a @Value field in each test method? Should I refactor my code to access it differently?

**SOLUTION**
Thanks to Borys Zibrov it works with this code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(PasswordController.class)
public class PasswordControllerTest extends OtpTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Test
  public void newRoute_developmentModeIsTrue_passwordIsInTheResponseBody() throws Exception {
    PasswordController controller = applicationContext.getBean(PasswordController.class);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(controller, "isDevelopmentMode", true);

    given(manager.generatePassword(any(String.class))).willReturn("123456");

    mockMvc.perform(post("/new").param(PasswordController.USERNAME_PARAM, "test_user")).andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().string("New password: 123456"));
  }
}
```

Getting my controller bean from the application context didn't work at first because in my previous code I was using my test class in WebMvcTest annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create another `applicationContext-tests.xml`, connect it to your test via:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(PasswordControllerTest.class)
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = "path_to applicationContext-tests.xml")
})
public class PasswordControllerTest extends OtpTest {
```

and override that property `development.mode` there.

You could also stick to using `ReflectionTestUtils` but instead of a direct instantiation use a bean from applicationContext constructed by spring for you, and then set a property on that bean.

Or you could just provide a setter for that field.

Comment: Thank you Borys for your reply. I'm not sure to understand: with your solution, how can I have 2 unit tests in the same test class, one to test development.mode = true, and the other with false? What I understand is that I would have to create two classes, with 2 applicationContext files, am I wrong?

Comment: ah yes, for that case you'll have to create two classes. another option is to use ReflectionTestUtils but take controller from applicationContext instead of a direct instantiation.

Comment: or you could just provide a setter for the field

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked well with the application context and the reflection